# Dynamic invoke command with different parameters

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell script, I want to read a CSV file that contains something like this:

```
Type  Title      Param1        Param2       
----  -----      ------        ------       
Type1 Foo type 1 ValueForType1              
Type2 Foo type 2               ValueForType2
```

When type is `Type1`, I have to call a function named `New-FooType1`, when type is `Type2`, the funcation is named `New-FooType2`, and so on:

```
function New-FooType1{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Title,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Param1
    )

    Write-Host "New-FooType1 $Title with $Param1"
}

function New-FooType2{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Title,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Param2
    )

    Write-Host "New-FooType2 $Title with $Param2"
}
```

I'm trying to **route** the call to either of the functions, using a dynamic invocation:

```
$csv | % {
    $cmdName = "New-Foo$($_.Type)"
    Invoke-Command (gcm $cmdName) -InputObject $_

}
```

However, I always get an error:

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

As you can see, different type mean different parameters set.

How can I solve this? I would like to avoid manipulating properties manually, because in my real life script, I have a dozen of different types, with up to 6 parameters.

Here is a complete repro sample of the issue:

```
$csvData = "Type;Title;Param1;Param2`nType1;Foo type 1;ValueForType1;;`nType2;Foo type 2;;ValueForType2"

$csv = ConvertFrom-csv $csvData -Delimiter ';'

$csv | ft -AutoSize

function New-FooType1{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Title,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Param1
    )

    Write-Host "New-FooType1 $Title with $Param1"
}

function New-FooType2{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Title,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Param2
    )

    Write-Host "New-FooType2 $Title with $Param2"
}


$csv | % {
    $cmdName = "New-Foo$($_.Type)"
    Invoke-Command (gcm $cmdName) -InputObject $_

}
```

The expected output of this script is:

```
New-FooType1 Foo type 1 with ValueForType1
New-FooType2 Foo type 2 with ValueForType2
```

Comment: `$_|&"New-Foo$($_.Type)"`

Comment: @PetSerAl: this works! you should post an answer. I'll reward you

Comment: In most cases I would just modify the function to accept a `Type` by parameter value. For example `New-Foo -Type 'Type2'` or `New-Foo -Type 'Type1'`. Then it's easy to just pass in the correct parameter.

Comment: @DarkLite1: most of time I'd agree. But in this specific case, I have too much Type values, and I think having separate methods will be easier to handle than multlipliying parametersetname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke command by name you should use invoke operator `&`. `Invoke-Command` cmdlet support only `ScriptBlock` and file invocation, and file invocation only supported for remote calls.

For dynamic parameter binding you can use spatting, but in that case you have to convert `PSCustomObject`s, returned by `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet, to `Hashtable`. You also have to strip any extra parameters from `Hashtable` because splatting will fail if you try to bind non-existing parameter.

Another approach for dynamic parameter binding would be to use binding from pipeline object. It looks like it is what you want to do, since you mark all your parameters with `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` option. And this approach will just ignore any extra property it can not bind to parameter. I recommend you to remove `ValueFromPipeline` option, because with this option in case of absence of property with parameter name PowerShell will just convert `PSCustomObject` to string (or to whatever type you use for parameter) and pass it as value for parameter.

So, all you need is to pass object by pipeline and use invoke operator for invocation of command with dynamic name:

```
$_ | & "New-Foo$($_.Type)"
```

Comment: Not sure to understand the difference with my first attempt, but it works. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the call operator `&`:

```
$CmdName = "New-FooType1"
$Arguments = "type1"

& $CmdName $Arguments
```

the call operator also supports [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) if you want the arguments bound to specific named parameters:

```
$Arguments = @{
    "title" = "type1"
}

& $CmdName @Arguments
```

Answer (score -2):

dont know exactly what your trying to do, but
Invoke-Command (gcm $cmdName) ?

Try invoke-expression $cmdname

Comment: how do you pass the parameters with invoke-expression